# Why does use of := with fmt.Scanf in Go always return 1?

Tags: parsing, go, scanf

Here is the code:

```
var n int
a, _ := fmt.Scanf("%d",&n)
```

Then `a == 1`, `n` has changed its value by input. Why does use of `:=` with fmt.Scanf in Go always return 1?

Comment: What did you expect instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`fmt.Scanf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scanf) returns the number of successfully scanned items:

> Scanf scans text read from standard input, storing successive space-separated values into successive arguments as determined by the format. **It returns the number of items successfully scanned.** If that is less than the number of arguments, err will report why.

So if your input is a valid integer number fitting into an `int`, `fmt.Scanf()` will succeed to parse it and store it in `n`, and so it will return 1.

Should you input an invalid number (e.g. the `string` value `"a"`), scanning would not succeed, so `0` would be returned along with a non-`nil` error, like in this example:

```
var n int
a, err := fmt.Sscanf("a", "%d", &n)
fmt.Println(a, err)
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/QT0BRidlpT)):

```
0 expected integer
```